# Slow SQL query when join two tables, any way to improve the query speed?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Slow SQL query when join two tables, any way to improve the query speed?

I have a small table A and large table B. A has all column we need, except TYPE column, and the TYPE value can be only found in B. But B have too many useless rows.

Now I want to select all rows from A, and they should have all column plus TYPE. My idea is use left join as it can select all rows from B which exist in A, so we can get the TYPE value.

Oracle:

```
SELECT B.HOUR, B.LOCATION, B.PRICE, B.TYPE, B.DATE
FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.HOUR=B.HOUR AND A.LOCATION=B.LOCATION AND A.PRICE=B.PRICE AND A.DATE=B.DATE
```

It is very slow. Besides, I only have read privilege so I cannot create new table. Is there any method to improve it? Thanks.

Comment: Table and index definitions please.

Comment: Make sure all the columns in your ON clause are indexed

Comment: Without any privileges but read, you can't do much.

Comment: Run an explain plan and post results

Comment: I think you want inner join

Comment: Why do you use a left join instead of an inner join? Do you have rows in A you do not have in B? Than why do you just select B values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the actual data or being able to add indexes, etc it is hard to provide advice, but there a couple of approaches you can try:

a) Use an Exists instead of the JOIN

```
SELECT B.HOUR, B.LOCATION, B.PRICE, B.TYPE, B.DATE
FROM B
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM A 
               WHERE A.HOUR=B.HOUR AND A.LOCATION=B.LOCATION AND A.PRICE=B.PRICE AND A.DATE=B.DATE)
```

b) Group the larger 'B' table in a CTE or into a temp table

```
;WITH data as (
     SELECT B.HOUR, B.LOCATION, B.PRICE, B.TYPE, B.DATE
     FROM B
     GROUP BY B.HOUR, B.LOCATION, B.PRICE, B.TYPE, B.DATE
)
SELECT Data.HOUR, Data.LOCATION, Data.PRICE, Data.TYPE, Data.DATE
FROM   Data
          INNER JOIN A
            ON A.HOUR=Data.HOUR AND A.LOCATION=Data.LOCATION AND A.PRICE=Data.PRICE AND A.DATE=Data.DATE
```

It is possible that neither solution will work, but they may be worth a try

Answer (score 1):

For your query, you want an index on `b(hour, location, price, date)`.

The order of the columns does not really matter.

I think your query should be written as:

```
SELECT a.*, b.type
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.HOUR = B.HOUR AND A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION AND
        A.PRICE = B.PRICE AND A.DATE = B.DATE;
```

Comment: You are recommending a wildcard? You know that is wrong.  Just being lazy with your typing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the join is it's attempting to match multiple keys, and it none of them are integers. Instead of trying to fix that (you don't have permission anyway), use a subquery.

A subquery only takes the A rows and adds the single field in B with the matching criteria:

```
SELECT A.HOUR, A.LOCATION, A.PRICE,
      ,(SELECT TYPE
          FROM B
         WHERE B.HOUR = A.HOUR AND B.LOCATION = A.LOCATION 
               AND B.PRICE = A.PRICE AND B.DATE = A.DATE
       ) AS [Type]
      ,A.DATE
  FROM A
```